# Constraint function argument by it's return type

Tags: typescript, types

I have a reducer fabric that uses reducer result to affect fabric result.

Currently it works like so:

```js
const fabric: <T extends () => any>(reducer: T) => SomeValue<ReturnType<T>>
```

And now I can use it like so:

```js
const value = fabric(() => 1)
//     ^? -- SomeValue<number>
```

It correctly infers type from reducer return value.

But I want my reducer to get previous value also. I tried this type:

```js
const fabric: <T>(reducer: (prev: undefined | T) => T) => SomeValue<T>
```

It works ok on this call:

```js
const value = fabric((prevValue: number = 1) => prevValue + 1)
//     ^? -- SomeValue<number>
```

But it breaks infer if I skip first argument type and first example breaks:

```js
const value = fabric((prevState = 1) => prevState)
//     ^? -- SomeValue<unknown> instead of SomeValue<number>
```

Here's minimal example: [reproducable example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.9.5#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgNQIYBsCuEA8AVAPigF4oBvKAN2oC4o8oBfAKGYBMIBjdVAJ2k5wAdgGdgUAGaoARrwCWnGsygqo%20AgAp%20bTJwi86GqGH6U6mIRwlyhENlAA%209AJQkieZ8SLwkaLLkJWQVFxSgxsAEYSSRl5Tg0jEwhKP2w6IUwEaX1oiNcvY1NU6ABqKDzmAHpK1RUAPQB%20IOExKnCIACZoqVkFBPyiCuraqEbmkLb-ABZu2L7EovbcgcLk4qgyoZqRseZg1okhaI1UZbcoVCrtkdUxoA).

Is there any way to prioritize return type over argument in type inference?

Comment: Could you make this a [mre]? What's `SomeValue`?  If I make something up [I can't even reproduce it](https://tsplay.dev/mL89vm).

Comment: @jcalz `SomeValue` doesn't really matter. [This is the example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.9.5#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgNQIYBsCuEA8AVAPigF4oBvKAN2oC4o8oBfAKGYBMIBjdVAJ2k5wAdgGdgUAGaoARrwCWnGsygqo+AgAp+bTJwi86GqGH6U6mIRwlyhENlAA+9AJQkieZ8SLwkaLLkJWQVFxSgxsAEYSSRl5Tg0jEwhKP2w6IUwEaX1oiNcvY1NU6ABqKDzmAHpK1RUAPQB+IOExKnCIACZoqVkFBPyiCuraqEbmkLb-ABZu2L7EovbcgcLk4qgyoZqRseZg1okhaI1UZbcoVCrtkdUxoA) where inference breaks.

Comment: It matters to the extent that different versions could possibly affect inference. The point of a [mre] is to make things that don't matter fade into the background instead of immediately causing errors people need to resolve.  If you're happy with `{vvv: T}` then put it in the question so that nobody has to worry about it.

Comment: Anyway given the actual problem example, I'd say this is a variant of [ms/TS#47599](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47599) without a simple fix; The function `(p = 1) => p` is context sensitive and generic type inference doesn't always play nicely with contextual type inference. The situation has steadily improved but there are still bad cases (and there will probably always be without *full unification* as described in [ms/TS#30134](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30134)). Does that fully address your q? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz if fabric return type may affect inference then [here the full example is](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=5.0.2#code/C4TwDgpgBA6gTgQzAHgCoD4oF4oG8oBuAXFKlAL4BQoksiYAwggHbAASA9gDYAmAYszSYc+YqQqVKAYw7MAzsCgAzBACMSuSlG1QhACjgQeAVykQ4JPWAD8JVAEpsmByXhIhAGi07kAZXR6AJbMgcAIXL5hwBAkvvau9EysnLwCfuiU5NhQemJWJCwg9ljohVAAPlCFjiU5uATk9pIy8ooEAIzZKqp6elBghgQAauHGMVDMxgC2qubZ7TWYAxDDo9AA1FALlAD0OzpQAHrWzbIKhABMXWq9i1tNewfHp62EAMzXPduPTycv5wQACyfXr9QbzO7LAhQTbffYHI5-FrnJTMbJ6BAQpxVXbwhE6Z7SM5tACsIL6UJIkxmcxwCxICjgwQA5tiAORsh547TPIA).

Comment: @jcalz the example in previous comment have also function overloading. But I thought it's better solve problems one by one so I haven't mention it in this q.

Comment: Since it isn't working with the simplest case of just `void` as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/WJV9rW), we should probably reduce the question to that to be a [mre].  I agree that adding more pieces to it should only come after solving the simpler version... but unfortunately I don't see a way to do it (other than to just sidestep it like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wj05lm)), as mentioned in my previous comment.  So at this point, do you want to see an answer talking about ms/TS#47599 and limitations of TS's inference algorithm? Or is there something I'm missing about the situation?

Comment: Yeah, I guess that inference algorithm limitation is the answer here. Would love to read the whole explanation!

Comment: Okay it's close to my bedtime now so it might not be until 8+ hours from now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript's inference algorithm isn't perfect by any means, and sometimes it fails to infer types even when there's a provably "correct" type to infer.  Theoretically it could be reimplemented to be a *full [unification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science))* algorithm, as discussed in [microsoft/TypeScript#30134](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30134), in which case inference would always be correct, but [according to the TS language architect](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17520#issuecomment-318935065) in [microsoft/TypeScript#17520](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17520), the current algorithm "has the distinct advantage of being able to make partial inferences in incomplete code which is hugely beneficial to statement completion in IDEs."  Without full unification, TypeScript will inevitably fail to infer types in some cases.

In your case, `fabric((p = 1) => p)` needs to infer both the type of `p` [contextually](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) (meaning that `(p = 1) => p` is a *context-sensitive* function) and the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type argument `T` in the definition of `fabric` at the same time.  The "right" thing to do would be to infer `p` first as `number` from its definition, ignoring any possible dependence of `p` on `T`, and then use that to infer `T` as `number`.  But what actually happens is that the compiler *defers* inference of the context sensitive function until after it has inferred `T`, at which point it's too late because there's nothing else from which `T` can be inferred.

Even though some failures of inference are inevitable, it doesn't mean any particular case is.  It's possible that, if filed as a bug/suggestion, your case could be supported.  There has been steady improvement in the compiler's ability to infer generics and contextual types at the same time, such as [TS4.7's added support for inferring within objects and methods](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#improved-function-inference-in-objects-and-methods).  But right now, as of TS5.0, it's a limitation, and there doesn't seem to be a way to change the definition of `fabric()` to get inference to work for a function like `(p = 1) => p`.

---

Until and unless support is improved here, you'll have to work around it, much as you have shown in your question.  The best workaround is probably just to either [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#parameter-type-annotations) the context-sensitive parameter or to manually specify the generic type argument, to relieve the compiler of the responsibility of inferring both:

```
declare const fabric:
    <T>(reducer: (prev: undefined | T) => T) => void

fabric((prevValue: number = 1) => prevValue + 1)
// const fabric: <number>(reducer: (prev: number | undefined) => number) => void

fabric<number>((prevValue = 1) => prevValue + 1)
// const fabric: <number>(reducer: (prev: number | undefined) => number) => void
```

Or you could declare the callback separately so that there's no generic inference involved:

```
const fn = (prevValue = 1) => prevValue + 1;
fabric(fn);
// const fabric: <number>(reducer: (prev: number | undefined) => number) => void
```

Either way you'll have to do the work the compiler is unable to do.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=5.0.2#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gMygIxgEswAuAKHkvgB4AVAPgAo5gBXMEGE+RgBzgBu3VilDZCKEMHgAfeLQCU8ALz15S1fAFJCwMmVwFijPoIBqUCKxDcUrALZ5OK+AEYNa-iAEWrCANRuCmQA9CGIqJg4+ESkNHaOnEws7Jzcpt62Dk4wsvAiYhJSHvAJOSXauvqGsdRlSSZePpbWLu4qnuYtAUGh4cjoWDXE3HXZDSkcXDxNWYm5cgUg4pLAJfUwFTp6ZANR2CguGc1+bSVNvq2BrgDcBjHGBwp3YRGD0UZxY-PJUqnTxzmOTySxWxQ6pXGmwhlT0QA)